# CRISPR Sequence Finder and Database Download

Tags: database, software-recommendation, data-retrieval, crispr, bacteria

I am searching for tools to pull CRISPR Spacers from Bacterial Genomes. I am aware of the [CRISPRDB](http://crispr.i2bc.paris-saclay.fr/) and the corresponding identification tool on the web server.

- Are there other tools for finding CRISPR Spacers?
- Is there a way to download the spacer sequences from CRISPRDB?
- Is there another database that contains all validated / inferred bacterial CRISPR sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRT (CRISPR Recognition Tool) http://www.room220.com/crt/

Crisprs Finder Online Tool https://crispr.i2bc.paris-saclay.fr/Server/

Piler-CR http://www.drive5.com/pilercr/

(Omic Tools List) https://omictools.com/crispr-detection-category